# How to fix - Access to fetch at 'https://login.windows.net......' has been blocked by CORS policy - when logging back in

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm having a problem with my React / ASP.net core web API app and authentication with Azure AD.

The first time I log in it's all fine. Then if I sign out, I get presented with the Microsoft hosted "You have been signed out. Return to the website" page, which has a link back to the site.
If I then click on that link then the app hangs when it tries to authenticate, and I'm getting CORS errors in my Chrome browser console:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://login.windows.net/XXXXX/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=
>   (etc)' (redirected from
>   'https://uat.xxxxx.com/coreservice/api/foo?page=1&pageSize=25') from
>   origin 'https://uat.xxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Extra info:

- As an experiment I hosted a link to the site from elsewhere on the web and I get the same problematic behaviour if I click on that link.
- If I hard refresh the page at this point, then it all works fine - I'm presented with the MS Azure login page as expected.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? I have the same error.

Comment: @user1857450 This was resolved, but I'm afraid I can't remember how (it may have been another dev on our team). However what I do remember is that the CORS error was a bit of a red herring - there was nothing wrong with our CORS config - the underlying problem was somewhere else in our application.
Sorry that's probably not terribly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the Azure Web Apps to host your application, but the issue I had was that I was using the App Service Authentication setting under Authentication/Authorization in the Azure Portal.  This setting was pointing to the Azure AD instance.  But I also was using [React-ADAL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal) npm package wrapped around my application so it was causing conflicting issues since they were both using the same instance of Azure AD.

I turned off the App Service Authentication setting in the Azure portal and everything worked from there.

This setting does work as I have used it with other applications and simple web apps but I realized that the Azure App Auth setting was conflicting with the React-ADAL npm package.

Hope this helps.